# count database rows by id

Tags: php, sql

---

I'm trying to count the `$active_ids` from the database. But I'm not figuring out how to do it best. As a disclaimer, I'm still learning MySQL/PHP.

this is what it echo's right now

> 1, 3, 4, 1, 1

and is what it will look like if it's counted

> 3, 1 ,1

---

```
    <?php

    $active_ids = '1, 3, 4';

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ({$active_ids})";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        if($result->num_rows > 0){

                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo $row['username'], "<br/>";
                }

            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timetable WHERE dj IN ({$active_ids})";
            $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo $row['dj'], "<br/>";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Couldn't really understand what you are trying to achieve. `3,1,1` are the counts of the appearance of `$active_ids` ?

Comment: yes that's what needs to come out of the db in place of 1, 3, 4, 1, 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know PHP, but I know SQL. It sounds like you want to use a GROUP BY clause, like this:

```
select dj, count(*) as n from timetable
    where dj in ({$active_ids})
    group by dj
```

Each row selected will have two columns. The first column (named “dj”) is the dj's user id, and the second column (named “n”) is the number of entries in timetable with that dj's id. You should be able to print the count like this:

```
echo $row['n'], "<br/>";
```

Comment: This still echo's out the database's results and not the counted

Comment: You need to look at the second column to get the count.