# Fetch assoc error

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, union, fetch

### Hello

i'm trying to make a table with this query but i cant get it to work. the thing is that it cant select 2 query's at a time but i dont know another way for it..

```
$active_ids = '1, 3, 4';
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ({$active_ids})";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);   

$query = "SELECT dj, count(*) AS n FROM timetable WHERE dj IN ({$active_ids}) GROUP BY dj";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['username'], "<br/>";
    echo $row['n'], "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Is it column `dj`in `users` table?

Comment: you posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382038/count-database-rows-by-id - what's different from this one? you got an answer also.

Comment: i need to add the query's into 1 query

Comment: @Imran no the dj is in timetable and username in users

Comment: So what's the foreign key from table `users` you need to pass to `timetable` ?

Comment: Right now you are just redeclaring your variable and losing the data. Look at using a UNION query. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: you could also use 2 different variable names eg : $reult and $result1...

Comment: @NurBar cant because then i cant make a table with it

Comment: why not? you can either use an and condition (while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() && $row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) or you could add $row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc() inside the loop and get the data you need....

Comment: already tryed that and it didnt work @NurBar

Comment: @ShadMickelberry i'm not good with SQL and cant get it to work ...

Comment: Assuming that dj is a foreign key for users.id you could also just do another query inside your while loop. So $query2 = "SELECT count(*) from timetable where dj = {$row['id']}"

Comment: then it doesnt count anymore @ShadMickelberry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$active_ids = '1, 3, 4';
$result = $mysqli->query("
    (SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ({$active_ids}))
    UNION 
    (SELECT dj, count(*) AS n FROM timetable WHERE dj IN ({$active_ids}) GROUP BY dj)
") ;

if (!$rec = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo ("Sorry, no records found");
}
else {
    do {
        echo ($rec["username"]);
        echo "<br />";
        echo ($rec["n"]);
        echo "<br />";
    }
    while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     $active_ids = '1, 3, 4'; 

    $query = "SELECT users.* from users 
              LEFT JOIN timetable ON users.id=timetable.dj
                  WHERE users.id IN ({$active_ids})
              UNION
              SELECT timetable.dj,timetable.count(*) as n from timetable
              RIGHT JOIN users ON timetable.dj=users.id
                  WHERE timetable.dj IN ({$active_ids}) GROUP BY timetable.dj
    ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);    

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['username'], "<br/>";
        echo $row['n'], "<br/>";
    }
```

I don't know it is certainly true but can you try this code ?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Admin\_res\core\home.php on line 75

Comment: can you write your columns and rows of your tables ? it will be easier.